# Isekai manhua/manhwa where the female lead marries a crown prince at a young age

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, webcomics

The female (who has pinkish hair) lead married the crown prince at a young age, which was planned by the queen so that he wouldn't marry someone else who would boost his status.

The queen wants her son to become crown prince, but her son doesn't want to be the king.

The female lead also helps change the law so that the heroine could become duchess and have power that doesn't require her to marry the prince.

Comment: Wait, so did she marry him or didn't she?

Comment: The title says isekai, but the question mentions nothing of the sort. Was there anything actually isekai about that? Was the  prince, the queen, anyone, actually transported into this world? I'm asking because there's nothing science-fiction of fantasy in this question, save for that "isekai" mention; but then again, more and more manhuas get labelled as isekai when they don't even involve world-crossing anymore.

Answer (score 3):

This is *[This Villainess Wants a Divorce!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/this-villainess-wants-a-divorce)*, aka *Survive as the Hero's Wife*. It is an isekai.

> We all hate the greedy villains hell-bent on sabotage. Enter Carnelia Easter, the awful secondary villainess of the romance I’m reading, who trapped the prince in marriage at the behest of the evil empress. I didn’t shed a tear when her head’s lopped off, but now I’m Carnelia!

[image: Cover]

The empress has the main character marry the prince and act as her spy as she tries to ensure her son becomes the next emperor.

Later in the story the main character does help another woman inherit the title of duchess by changing the empire's laws; it's been a while since I read this so I don't recall if she was the heroine of the original novel or not, but the event does happen.